# Troubles setting up Rally to Jira Connector

Tags: ruby, xml, methods, jira, rally

I am working with Jira/Rally and the the Ruby connector.  I was tapped to test out the connector and make sure it will do everything we need.  I have to confess that this isn't my area of expertise, I am unable to find relevant help on the Rally site and the previous topics here were tied to different issues.

The error I am running into is:

```
[2013-01-18 15:21:38 Z] DEBUG : Finding method getIssuesFromJqlSearch
[2013-01-18 15:21:39 Z] ERROR : ConnectorRunner.rescue in run_services - Unexpected exception occurred
[2013-01-18 15:21:39 Z] ERROR : ConnectorRunner.exception - Message undefined method `key' for nil:NilClass
[2013-01-18 15:21:39 Z] ERROR : ConnectorRunner.exception - Stack Trace
```

I am connecting to both services just fine (after having worked through some fun proxy issues), and am working off the base jira_config.xml that comes with the connector.  I have changed only the required fields, ie UN/PW/URL/Project/Workspace

Relevant xml code:

```
<RallyConnection>
        <Url>rally1.rallydev.com</Url>
        <WorkspaceName>CMSJiraIntegrationTestWorkspace</WorkspaceName>
        <Projects>
            <Project>Sample Project</Project>
        </Projects>
        <User>***************</User>
        <Password>encoded-T-i-F-j-b-2-x-l-M-j-A-=-</Password>
        <ArtifactType>Defect</ArtifactType>
        <ExternalIDField>JiraDefectKey</ExternalIDField>
        <CrosslinkUrlField>JiraLink</CrosslinkUrlField>
    </RallyConnection>
    <JiraConnection>
        <Url>http://10.34.10.175:8080</Url>
        <User>***************</User>
        <Password>encoded-a-m-F-t-Z-X-M-u-Y-m-V-p-b-n-M-=-</Password>
        <ArtifactType>Bug</ArtifactType>
        <Project>SP</Project>
        <ExternalIDField>RallyID</ExternalIDField>
        <CrosslinkUrlField>RallyURL</CrosslinkUrlField>
        <CopySelectors>
          <CopySelector>Status != Closed</CopySelector>
        </CopySelectors>
    </JiraConnection>
```

Does anyone have insight as to why this would fail?

The help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've got JIRA remote API enabled? It seems to crash just after looking for SOAP method "getIssuesFromJqlSearch".

Could you please post the full log file generated from starting the connector to when it crashed?